How to remove SSIS .dtsx package from a project in Visual Studio Community 2022
Recently had to upgrade to visual studio community 2022. I have solutions that were created in a previous version. I can open and execute the solutions in 2022. The problem I'm having is when I want to delete / remove a .dtsx package from a project within the solution.
I'll right click on the package and click 'exclude from project'. I save and close the solution. However, when I re-open the solution, the package I just excluded is showing as a tab, but it's not listed in SSIS packages on the Solution Explorer. I've even tried right clicking a package and selecting 'delete' from the options. When I do this, the solution throws an error when opening because it can't find the package I just deleted.
I never had this problem with the prior version of Visual Studio I was using. Unfortunately, I can't go back to that version due to company policy.
Has anyone experienced a similar issue of not being able to remove a package from a project and have you found a solution?
Appreciate any help you can provide.
Thanks

Looking into the comments coming in to Microsoft related to developing SSIS on Visual Studio 2022 it is pretty clear to me that Microsoft is not putting a lot of resources working on these bits. We are monitoring this and we are still on 2019 due to the fact that the situation seems pretty unstable related to the tooling.
